# How to reload a JSF page from a ValueChangeEvent?

Tags: jsf

I have a selectonemenu where a change in the selection should navigate the user to the related page.

So, how do I simulate the action handling of a commandbutton using a selectonemenu control (or are there a more elegant ways to achieve this)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't go around a shot of Javascript for this. Basically you need to let the Javascript submit the request to the server side. In a HTML `<select>` element (which is been generated by the JSF `h:selectOneMenu`) you can best use the `onchange` attribute for this. Any JS which you attach to this event will be invoked whenever the user changes the value of the element.

```
<h:selectOneMenu onchange="this.form.submit();">
```

or if you're lazy in writing, this shorthand is also correct:

```
<h:selectOneMenu onchange="submit()">
```

This will submit the form in combination with the firstnext HTML `input type="submit"` element inside the same form (which is been generated by the JSF `h:commandButton`).

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.page}" onchange="submit()" required="true">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select page.." />
        <f:selectItems value="#{bean.pages}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
    <h:commandButton value="other" action="#{bean.other}" /> <!-- won't be submitted -->
</h:form>
```

You need to write logic in the action method which causes the navigation action as definied in `faces-config.xml` to be taken place. Example:

```
public String submit() {
    return this.page;
}
```

If you do **not** want to use an `commandButton`, then you can also go ahead with abusing the `valueChangeListener`:

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.page}" onchange="submit()"
        valueChangeListener="#{bean.change}" required="true">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select page.." />
        <f:selectItems value="#{bean.pages}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

In the bean you then have:

```
public void change(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    String page = (String) event.getNewValue(); // Must however be the exact page URL. E.g. "contact.jsf".
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(page);
}
```

Alternatively, if you already have the desired URL's as `f:selectItem` values, then you can also go ahead with just only JS and no bean actions:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.page}"
    onchange="window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select page.." />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="home" itemValue="home.jsf" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="faq" itemValue="faq.jsf" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="contact" itemValue="contact.jsf" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<h:selectOneMenu onchange="document.getElementById('myform').submit();" ...>
```