# JSF Language switcher and ajax update

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, facelets

This question is a follow - up of the older [Language switcher implementation in JSF 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204001/language-switcher-implementation-in-jsf).

The substance of the question is still valid, although PrimeFaces has released some newer builds, and my JSF knowledge is a bit better than before.

To summarize, I have a single xhtml page, fully ajaxified.

The language switcher is this:

```
<h:form id="selectLanguage" >
    <p:commandLink action="#{languageSwitcher.setLanguage('it')}" rendered="#{languageSwitcher.language!='it'}" >
        <h:graphicImage library ="images" name="it.gif" title="it" />
    </p:commandLink>
    <p:commandLink action="#{languageSwitcher.setLanguage('en')}" rendered="#{languageSwitcher.language!='en'}" >
        <h:graphicImage library ="images" name="en.gif" title="en" />
    </p:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

I want that when **`it`** is chosen, only the **`en`** flag is displayed, and viceversa. And I want that all the stuff in the web page is updated with the Resource Bundle translations.

In particular, I have some `p:dialog`S whose header attributes need to be updated as well.
The dialog forms are inside each dialog:

```
<p:dialog header="#{msgs.myHeader}"  ... >
    <h:form .... />
</p:dialog >
```

The rest of the page is a `<p:layout>` containing some layoutUnits. Each `layoutUnit` contains a form with other components that need to be translated as well.

LanguageSwitcher is a `SessionScoped` `JSF Managed Bean`.

I have tried all of the following ways:

1. `<f:ajax render="@all" />` inside the `p:commandLink` braces
2. `update="@all"` attribute inside `p:commandLink`
3. `<p:ajax update="@all" />` inside the `p:commandLink` braces

Unfortunately, none of them works.

I have tried with `@all`, although I am available to insert the ids of the forms, they are not so many. Problem is that the dialog headers are not updated in this way.

I am using PrimeFaces 3.4.1 - Mojarra 2.1.13

Comment: haven't read the entire question, but how about simple `<h:commandButton` without ajax ?

Comment: Which browser did you use? PrimeFaces' `@all` fails in IE as to postprocessing the retrieved JavaScript (fix is scheduled for 3.4.2). `<f:ajax>` doesn't work in `<p:commandLink>` at all, use `<h:commandLink>` for that instead.

Comment: Thanks to both for your precious comments. @Daniel : I need ajax indeed.

Comment: @BalusC : You are right, PrimeFaces's ajax `all` fails in IE. Unfortunately the problem appears to be present also in 3.4.2 . I also have problems in making it work h:commandLink: it doesn't update the headers of a p:dataTable. Will investigate further

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that 3.4.2 is already out. Indeed, the fix is not in 3.4.2 yet, the associated issue report says that it's now retargeted for 3.5. Sorry for the misinformation. But, as you confirmed the IE issue, are you implying that your particular use case works properly in the other browsers? Just to be sure before posting a wrong answer :)

Comment: @BalusC I've only tested on FF: it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `update="@all"` of all PrimeFaces versions until now (3.4.2) is known to fail in IE. Any JavaScript code delivered along with the ajax response isn't been initialized properly.

This is discussed in [this PrimeFaces forum topic](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=18937&start=20) and reported as [issue 4731](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4731).

Until they fix it, your best bet is to workaround it by loading the following piece of JavaScript on every view which (possibly) contains an `update="@all"` command:

```javascript
var originalPrimeFacesAjaxResponseFunction = PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxResponse;
PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxResponse = function(responseXML) {
   var newViewRoot = $(responseXML.documentElement).find("update[id='javax.faces.ViewRoot']").text();

    if (newViewRoot) {
       $('head').html(newViewRoot.substring(newViewRoot.indexOf("<head>") + 6, newViewRoot.indexOf("</head>")));
       $('body').html(newViewRoot.substring(newViewRoot.indexOf("<body>") + 6, newViewRoot.indexOf("</body>")));
    } else {
        originalPrimeFacesAjaxResponseFunction.apply(this, arguments);
    }
};
```

Provide this in flavor of a JS file which is loaded by `<h:outputScript target="head">` inside the `<h:body>` in order to enforce the right loading order.

```
<h:body>
    <h:outputScript name="script.js" target="head" />
    ...
</h:body>
```